# Using the CSS grid layout with dynamically created rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid-layout

I'm trying to use the CSS grid layout in order to style a "controller" with dynamically created rows.  I'm having trouble getting the spacing right.

In what I have, the slider containers don't appear on their own rows (despite `grid-auto-rows: auto`) and the content within a slider container doesn't appear in the same row (despite `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr`).  There's also some weird unexpected spacing happening between the 2nd and 3rd columns (which aren't supposed to exist anyways).

Ultimately what I'd like is for each row to contain 1 label, 1 slider, and 1 value (all related to each other) and for the elements in each column to be the same width, preferably the minimum width necessary to hold the content with the max length in the respective column.

Things that I'm curious about are

- Whether or not this controller should have absolute positioning / an absolute width (how would I make it so that the width fits the contents?)
- How can I write the CSS in such a way that it resizes nicely as the user resizes their screen
- If the label column width is the minimum of the maximum of all label contents and the value column width is the minimum of the maximum of all value contents, if I set a minimum width for the slider, that should give me the minimum width for the container, right?
- If the rows are dynamically created, how can I reference them via the `grid-row` property?

Thanks for the help.

```js
var slidersContainer = document.createElement("div");
slidersContainer.id = "sliders-container";

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(slidersContainer);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var sliderContainer = document.createElement("div");
  sliderContainer.className = "slider-container";
  slidersContainer.appendChild(sliderContainer);

  var label = document.createElement("div");
  label.className = "slider-label"
  label.innerHTML = "some-label-" + i;
  sliderContainer.appendChild(label);

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.className = "slider";
  input.min = 0;
  input.max = 100;
  input.type = "range";
  sliderContainer.appendChild(input);

  var value = document.createElement("div");
  value.className = "slider-value";
  value.innerHTML = "0.0000001";
  sliderContainer.appendChild(value);
}
```

```css
#sliders-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.slider-container {}

.slider-label {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.slider {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.slider-value {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the *CSS grid* properties to the `slider-container` instead of the *absolutely positioned* container - see demo below:

```js
var slidersContainer = document.createElement("div");
slidersContainer.id = "sliders-container";

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(slidersContainer);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var sliderContainer = document.createElement("div");
  sliderContainer.className = "slider-container";
  slidersContainer.appendChild(sliderContainer);

  var label = document.createElement("div");
  label.className = "slider-label"
  label.innerHTML = "some-label-" + i;
  sliderContainer.appendChild(label);

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.className = "slider";
  input.min = 0;
  input.max = 100;
  input.type = "range";
  sliderContainer.appendChild(input);

  var value = document.createElement("div");
  value.className = "slider-value";
  value.innerHTML = "0.0000001";
  sliderContainer.appendChild(value);
}
```

```css
#sliders-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.slider-container { /* CHANGED */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.slider-label {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.slider {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.slider-value {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

Comment: @geofflittle let me know your thoughts on this, thanks!